# Unable to get browser instance using multiremote with typescript

Tags: typescript, webdriver-io

I need to run my tests in 2 different browsers simultaneously. I am trying to set up wdio to work with Multiremote settings but no luck. Not able to get the browser instance in my tests which is defined in multiremote config.

Below is my multiremote specific wdio configuration, **\multiremote.conf.ts**

```
const merge = require('deepmerge');
import * as wdioConf from './wdio.conf';

wdioConf.config.capabilities = [
  {
    myChromeBrowser: {
      capabilities: {
        browserName: 'chrome',
      },
    },
    myEdgeBrowser: {
      capabilities: {
        browserName: 'MicrosoftEdge',
      },
    },
  },
];

exports.config = merge(
  wdioConf.config,
  {
    specs: ['./build/specs/login.for.session.limit.enabled.browser2.spec.js'],
    maxInstances: 1,
    before() {
      browser.setWindowSize(1422, 626);
    },
  },

  { clone: false },
);
```

when I use `myChromeBrowser` instance in my tests, it's showing error

> Cannot find name 'myChromeBrowser'.ts(2304).

how to get the global instance to use specific browser in my tests?